# Using BinaryReader to read a midi file. (.net)

Tags: .net, midi, binaryreader

How would I use a BinaryReader to read a midi file (specifications for the format are [here](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm))

I'm using vb.net, but I'm willing to see other code (mostly just C#, I can convert it).  I'm working on a large project and this comes as a bit of a speedbump.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Function convertCharArrayToString(ByVal chars() As Char) As String
    Dim tReturn As String = ""
    For Each v As Char In chars
        tReturn &= v
    Next
    Return tReturn
End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    midiStatus = "Reading..."
    Dim midiStream As New StreamReader(midiFile)
    Dim nBR As New BinaryReader(midiStream.BaseStream)
    midiStatus = "Validating Midi File..."
    Dim HeaderA As String = convertCharArrayToString(nBR.ReadChars(4))
    If Not HeaderA = "MThd" Then Return
    Dim HeaderB() As Byte = nBR.ReadBytes(4)
    'Get Track Type
    midiStatus = "Reading Header Data..."
    Dim TrackType1 As Integer = nBR.ReadInt16()
    Dim TrackType2 As Integer = nBR.ReadInt16()
    MsgBox(TrackType1 & TrackType2)

End Sub
```

Everything works find up to when I start reading the actual Header Data.  I'm absoultly lost as to how I'm to continue.  Any help or code examples would be nice!

Comment: One byte at a time.  Ask a real question.

Comment: There were better ways you could have said that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your decoding logic in a class, not directly in the GUI.

Define a struct for the MIDI header, then use something like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0120__Class-Module/ReadRecordStructurefrombinaryfile.htm) to set it.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good.  Before I mark this as answered though, why are two values (ff?) supposed to equal one?  One data type is this.  It's supposed to be (in the end) 0, 1, or 2.  (this is all coming from the protocol/format information I included.

Comment: They used it as a filler. It's always going to be either `00 00`, `00 01`, or `00 02`. They didn't write it very clearly, IMO. My first MIDI decoder I wrote with this fine [reference](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) (sorry it took me so long to find it).